# How the price of a token is defined?

Tags: tokens, price

Already read this [How is the price of a token determined on Etherscan?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98237/how-is-the-price-of-a-token-determined-on-etherscan) but still not understand how a new fresh token is priced.

I mean .. I just create a token named "ABCD" with 1.000 of suply and deploy it into the BSC. Well ... how much is it costing in BUSD for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a liquidity pool. For example you create the pool in Quickswap with 500 USDT and 500 of your tokens, then your token can be bought or sold for $1. If someone buys (gives USDT to get tokens), the price of the token will go up, and if it sold (give tokens to get USDT) it will go down

Comment: how to calculate what price will be if I buy 5 tokens for 5 USDT? As input params we have 2 pools: in USDT and ETH, total pool count, transaction count (this is by Uniswap documentation)

Answer (score 1):

When you create an ERC20 token and deploy it on a blockchain network like BSC or Ethereum, the initial price of the ERC20 token is not automatically decited on-chain. Instead, the price of the token is typically established through trading on DEXs(like uniswap), or centralized exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

500 Tokens = 500 USD (You are determining the token value by adding it to the pool like uniswap)

Now the token Price is 1:1 (1 Token = 1 USD)

Someone Buy 20 Tokens (Giving 20 USD to the pool)

480 Tokens = 520 USD (20 Tokens sent to user and 20 USD sent to the pool from user)

Now the token price is 1 USD = 0.92 Tokens (Tokens/USD = Current Price)